# Insert seq.nextval and other distinct values

Tags: oracle, plsql

I want to make some changes to an existing stored procedure; insert the values in a table, first value will come from sequence and other values have to be distinct.

```
create SP_Emp()
.......
insert into table_emp(primary_key,name,dept,sal,id)
select distict
seq_emp.nextval,
first_value(name) over partition by(id),
id as id,
.....
.....
END;
```

The error it gives is sequence number not allowed here.

I want to insert the values, keeping the `seq.nextval` and all other values in the row distinct

Previously the procedure was:

```
create SP_Emp()
.......
insert into table_emp(name,dept,sal,id)

select distict

first_value(name) over partition by(id),
id as id,
.....
.....

END;
```

Answer (score 4):

Wrap your SQL statement in parenthesis as an inline view, and then add the sequence:

```
create SP_Emp()
.......
insert into table_emp(primary_key,name,dept,sal,id)
select seq_emp.nextval, s.*
from (
    select distinct
    first_value(name) over partition by(id),
    id as id,       
.....
        ) s
.....
END;
```